# What's "hybrid" vibration reduction in Nikon cameras?

Tags: nikon, image-stabilization

A number of Nikon cameras have image stabilization which Nikon markets as *VR* (vibration reduction). In some of these cameras there's a camera setting for *VR* - it can be *on*, *off* or *hybrid*.

*On* and *off* are obvious options. I cannot find any explanation of *hybrid*. What's that?

Comment: Compact cameras or DSLRs? Can you give some examples of camera models with this?

Comment: @vclaw A compact camera like COOLPIX AW110

Comment: I'll take a wild guess that it is meant for panning the camera, so it won't try to stabilize horizontal movement.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was a hot mess.

The AW110 manual describes it thusly:

> Record with optical compensation for camera shake during still picture
>   shooting using the lens shift method, and under the following
>   conditions, also performs electronic VR using image enhancement.

and then:

> When electronic VR in **On** **(hybrid)** operates, saving the picture
>   takes longer than normal, because when the picture is shot, the
>   shutter is released twice automatically to perform picture
>   compensation.

So, it *is* similar to the "dual" VR methods advertised in Nikon collateral, where two types of data are used to determine shake: optical VR and (probably) an accelerometer in the body. But it looks like it may sample and interpolate the image data twice so it can stop the action at slower shutter speeds. This may be why some people are saying it combines photos.

The utility must be quite constrained, though, because the manual has a laundry list of reasons why it will not take effect even if enabled.